# Ranking search Results with Keywords in SQL

Tags: java, sql, database-design, full-text-search, search-engine

I am having trouble starting this idea. I have an SQL database and an html interface with JAVA/Apache(tomcat). I was trying to make a simple database that sorts names of songs and matches to keywords about the songs. 
Example I have entered keywords like "epic , movies , queen , sing" and a song like queen bohemian rhapsody meets most of the criteria it is an "epic" song from a "movie" and preformed by "queen" so this would make a value of 3.
and also in the database a song like queen we are the champion would meet all keywords (epic,movie,queen,sing) -> so this song would be a 4.

I've dabbled with the count functions in sql and some JAVA code but i cant seen to find a way to shift through the keywords, or count them to see which result is better.

Where should I look to learn how to make something like this ?

---

Thank You very much for the explanation and the links . After hours of reading and re-reading I understand more about databases structure. And have a near functional webpage. I have one last question . The queries give me a result of the song_ID and the count. I have thought of a few ways to get the song name to also display.

1st idea I had was to add the name to the junction table.

2nd was create a temp table (view) and then use that info to seek data from the other tables.

3rd was write a java code to take the orginal results and then only display the song name and count. ....

I think I am missing something easy in SQL abilities to handle the data better (and more efficiently).

Comment: Start with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your database has two columns: tag and song_id, as such:

```
CREATE TABLE tags(tag STRING KEY, song_id INT);
```

Then you could do everything in a SQL query:

```
SELECT song_id, count(*)
FROM tags
WHERE tag IN ("epic", "movie", "queen", "sing")
GROUP BY song_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

If you want more complicated text search, i.e. if this solution ends up being too slow, you should look into Apache [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) and/or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: I think the troubled concept I am not grasping is how to search for multiple tags from different song_id('s).   Here is what I made from your advice .  The thing is I don't see any way to use a comma separator or delimiter for strings in SQL , or see how to make it function in java without taking the data and making it into a physical txt file. There must be a work around I am not understanding in Databases . Any suggestions ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE tags3(tag VARCHAR2(100), song_id INT,PRIMARY KEY(tag));

SELECT song_id, count(*)
FROM tags3
WHERE tag IN ('epic', 'queen', 'pain', 'rat')
GROUP BY song_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;

INSERT INTO tags3 (song_id , tag )
VALUES (1,'epic pain');
INSERT INTO tags3 ( song_id , tag )
VALUES (2,'total queen');
INSERT INTO tags3 ( song_id , tag)
VALUES (3,'epic queen');
INSERT INTO tags3 ( song_id , tag )
VALUES (4,'queen epic');
INSERT INTO tags3 (song_id , tag )
VALUES (5,'pain');

Answer (score 0):

Three tables:

- songs with a primary key `song_id` which is an integer
- tags with a primary key of `tag` which is a string
- songs-tags which is a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) that links the other two tables. It will have a composite primary key of `song_id` and `tag`

So if in songs we had these rows ([tuples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Relational_model)):

- song_id: 1; name: Bohemian Rhapsody
- song_id: 2; name: We Are The Champions

and in tags we had:

- tag: epic
- tag: movie
- tag: queen
- tag: sing

then in songs-tags we would have:

- song_id: 1; tag: epic
- song_id: 1; tag: movie
- song_id: 1; tag: queen
- song_id: 2; tag: epic
- song_id: 2; tag: movie
- song_id: 2; tag: queen
- song_id: 2; tag: sing

Now to find songs which match particular tags is just a question of selecting the relevant rows from the songs-tags tables.

The problem with your original design is that you are storing multiple tags in a single row. Instead you should have a separate row for each tag that matches a given song. If three tags match then you'll need three rows and so on.

You might want to read a bit about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to understand why your original design doesn't work effectively

(NB in Joe K's earlier answer he basically suggested the same thing and gave you an SQL query to determine which tags match which songs. I've just fleshed things out a bit more)